# Enable kdump on a compiled linux kernel

Tags: c, compilation, linux-kernel, kernel, crash-dumps

Ho to get a core dump on a changed Linux kernel ?

I am running a Ubuntu 14.04 VM with 4G ram, 4 cores, compiled and installed a 3.18 kernel.

> BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.18.7+
>   root=UUID=4a45cb37-0577-4307-bfc5-da80ee9097db ro
>   crashkernel=384M-:128M
>
> user@dhcp194:~/source/nfs4tc$ sudo kdump-config test   USE_KDUMP:
>   1   KDUMP_SYSCTL:      kernel.panic_on_oops=1   KDUMP_COREDIR:
>   /var/crash   crashkernel addr:  0x30000000   kdump kernel addr:
>   relocatable   kdump kernel:      /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.7+   kdump initrd:
>   /boot/initrd.img-3.18.7+   kexec command to be used:     /sbin/kexec
>   -p --command-line="BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.18.7+ root=UUID=4a45cb37-0577-4307-bfc5-da80ee9097db ro irqpoll maxcpus=1
>   nousb" --initrd=/boot/initrd.img-3.18.7+ /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.7+

kdump-load throws an error.

> user@dhcp194:~/source/nfs4tc$ sudo kdump-config load    Could not find
>   a free area of memory of 0x9521000 bytes...   locate_hole failed    *
>   failed to load kdump kernel

syslog snippet:

> /var/log/syslog.1:Apr  3 17:30:23 dhcp194 kdump-tools: failed to load
>   kdump kernel   /var/log/syslog.1:Apr  3 17:58:12 dhcp194 kdump-tools:
>   failed to load kdump kernel   /var/log/syslog.1:Apr  3 19:39:09
>   dhcp194 kdump-tools: failed to load kdump kernel

It works in a fresh installed VM, but after changing the kernel it wont. 
I use default .config file for kernel compilation. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's call a crash kernel - the one kdump must load, and system kernel - your host kernel.

1. Enable CONFIG_KEXEC in your system kernel
2. In your system kernel bootloader must pass crashkernel=YM@X string to your system kernel cmd line (possibly in your case through atags) where Y is a reserved space for your crash kernel (in MBs) and X is a physical address where crashkernel will be located.

To check 2. you could review /proc/iomem. If there is no "crash kernel" section in it, then something is going wrong.
And next ... use -d option in kexec utility for verbose mode